# Get whole <li> linked with wp_list_pages

Tags: customization, wp-list-pages, categories

I'm using wp_list_pages for my sidebar and it works fine to me, i just wanna add new feature which seems is not listed on codex or i don't know how to use it.

```
$args = array(
  'child_of'     => 284,
  'post_type'    => 'page',
  'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
  'sort_column' => 'post_date',
  'title_li'     => '', 
);
 ?>
<div id="#sidebar">
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS, as you see i get the '

' a background color with some padding.

```
#sidebar li {
font-size: .75em;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
background: #f18c21;
color: white;
```

So the think is, the only text on the li got the link, but what i would like to do is get the whole li section linked to the pages.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `wp_list_pages()` should already come in `<li><a>...</a></li>` format. Is this not what is happening or am I misunderstanding the question? If you want to have some more customization options you can use [`get_pages()` Function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and loop through the items yourself to tag and style them.

Comment: Exactly! 'wp_list_pages()' comes with '<li><a>..</a></li>' but what i want is <a><li>..</li></a>

Comment: Might I ask why you would like it as that? Not only is it not allowed in the HTML specifications but anything you need can surely be done in CSS.

Comment: This is my html output : http://s18.postimg.org/dotm2owop/Screen_Shot_2014_04_22_at_2_36_06_PM.png
I want to link whole the orange section not just the inside text, How can i do that with CSS?

Comment: Try `#sidebar li a {display: block;}` Then you can remove the styling off the list item and put them onto the anchor tag which should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said it's a question of the css-styles. Try something like

```
#sidebar li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The `a` tag gets the padding, not the `li`-tag